# Php/mysql check number of booked rooms

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a small issue regarding on how to check if a room is booked or not.

So basically I a have a table as shown below

**Accomm**

1. accomm_id
2. checkin  **[stored as timestamp]**
3. checkout  **[stored as timestamp]**

What I have so far, is that if the user inputs a checkin and checkout date which are both converted to timestamps. That part is done.

So what i have failed to figure out is the following:

- Search the `accomm` table for using the checkin and checkout paramters that the user entered.
- Then return the number of booked rooms.

Please assist or guide me on this one. Thanks.

```
$booked_rooms = 0;
while($accommodation_package = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    // $this->checkin, $this->checkout are values fed by the user
    // $accommodation_package['checkin/out'] are the values in the database
    if($this->checkin >= $accommodation_package['checkin'] && $this->checkout <= $accommodation_package['checkout']) {
        $booked_rooms +=1;
    }
}
echo $booked_rooms;
```

Well I thought the above would work but when checkin and checkout dates from the client are on different months it does not work.

Comment: Please show your current code that you are having issues with.

Comment: @Jono20201 . I have edited my post to include that

Comment: What the SQL query you have currently?

Comment: `"SELECT a.* FROM `accomm` a WHERE a.`client_id` IN (SELECT c.`client_id` FROM `client_details` c WHERE c.`booked` = 1)";`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have stored our check-in and check-out dates in the format 'd-m-Y' >ou could execute the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(acomm_id) FROM Accomm WHERE checkin <= yourDateString AND checkout => yourDateString
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have stored them as timestamps

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<?php
$currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(accomm_id)
        FROM accom
        WHERE checkin <= $currentTime
        AND checkout >= $currentTime";
$query = mysqli_query($sql);
// code to get the details.
```